# Touch punch - convert clicks to touches

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I started to use recently an awesome plug-in to convert touch evens to mouse clicks. But just today I came across one problem

```
jQuery('.draggable').click(function(){
  alert('clicked');
})
```

To fire alert I need to make two touches(mobile device), while on computer I need only one mouse click. What can be the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// set a var as false as a way to change and flag if something is being dragged

var dragCheck = false;
$('.element').draggable({
      revert: true,
   drag: function(){
            // On drag set that flag to true
         dragCheck = true;
   },
   stop: function(){
            // On stop of dragging reset the flag back to false
         dragCheck = false;
   }
});

// Then instead of using click use mouseup, and on mouseup only fire if the flag is set to false

$('.element') .bind('mouseup', function(){
      if(dragCheck == false){
           // do the click action here...
      }
});
```